# How to play video using Youtube Data API v3 and video id in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, youtube-data-api

I am receiving Youtube Video Id (i.e "par2cUNk8OE") from server, by using that id i want to play video in Windows phone universal application, i have searched a lot but not found any sample which will guide me. So can anyone tell me how to do that or any sample example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got MyToolkit Library wherer i can play my youtube Video

here is code for same

```
    try
    {//
        var pathUri = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("GC2qk2X3fKA", YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
        player.Source = pathUri.Uri;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is FormatException)
        {
            // handle exception. 
            // For example: Log error or notify user problem with file
        }
    }
```